# If has class get class name with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, class, variables

I have a div:

```
<div class="general_class class_1 class_2 color_ffffff"></div>
```

If this div has a class starting with 'color_' I need to retrieve the entire class name 'color_ffffff' in a jQuery variable.

```
var skin_color = jQuery('.general_class[class*=color_]');
```

On console log

```
console.log(skin_color);
```

I get the entire list of classes of the div.

Any idea?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var skin_color = $('.general_class[class*=color_]').attr('class').split(' '); // Gets all the classes in an array

var result =  skin_color
          .filter(  function(elem){ return elem.match(/color_*/) } ) // Removes elements not matching "color_*"
          .join('') // Transforms the array (normally containing one element) to a string

alert(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="general_class class_1 class_2 color_ffffff some other classname"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use regular expression to get the color:

```js
var elm = jQuery('.general_class[class*=color_]');
var re = /color_(.{6})/;
console.log(elm.attr('class').match(re));

// Yields ["color_ffffff", "ffffff"]
```

```html
<div class="general_class class_1 class_2 color_ffffff"></div>
```